# Who is responsible of generating the .idea files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, code-generation

When I'm looking on my Rails application folder i can find a **.idea** folder, it includes:

- .generators
- .rakeTasks

And more... When i open **.generators** for example, i see the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings><!--This file was automatically generated by Ruby plugin.
You are allowed to: 
1. Reorder generators
2. Remove generators
3. Add installed generators
To add new installed generators automatically delete this file and reload the project.
--><GeneratorsGroup><Generator name="active_record:migration" /><Generator name="active_record:model" /><Generator name="active_record:observer" /><Generator name="active_record:session_migration" /><Generator name="controller" /><Generator name="erb:controller" /><Generator name="erb:mailer" /><Generator name="erb:scaffold" /><Generator name="generator" /><Generator name="helper" /><Generator name="integration_test" /><Generator name="mailer" /><Generator name="metal" /><Generator name="migration" /><Generator name="model" /><Generator name="model_subclass" /><Generator name="observer" /><Generator name="performance_test" /><Generator name="plugin" /><Generator name="resource" /><Generator name="scaffold" /><Generator name="scaffold_controller" /><Generator name="session_migration" /><Generator name="stylesheets" /><Generator name="test_unit:controller" /><Generator name="test_unit:helper" /><Generator name="test_unit:integration" /><Generator name="test_unit:mailer" /><Generator name="test_unit:model" /><Generator name="test_unit:observer" /><Generator name="test_unit:performance" /><Generator name="test_unit:plugin" /><Generator name="test_unit:scaffold" /></GeneratorsGroup></Settings>
```

As you can see: "**This file was automatically generated by Ruby plugin.**"

So who is responsible of generating those files ?

and how can i call it ?

the IDE need to take care of it ?

Comment: I'm guessing it may come from RubyMine, which is based on Jet Brains' IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This folder and files are created if the application was opened at least once with Jet Brains' [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) or Jet Brains Intellij IDE.

All the user configuration regarding the project are saved in this directory.

If you delete this .idea folder and open the project in [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) these files will be generated again with fresh default Rubymine config.

Comment: There is another way of generating those files ? or only by writing a script ? 
Where does RubyMine gets the parameters from ?

Comment: @Danpe, You don't need to generate these files this are unnecessary unless you are using rubymine or any other jetbrains product as IDE and the IDE will manage everything of its config on its own, don't worry a lot about it :)

Comment: I actually wanna make a script that parses those files so I am worry about them :P

Comment: I dont know what you are upto but this ths official git repo for idea which is base of all jetbrains IDE https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community

Comment: where can i find the code that generates the .idea files? It's probbly gotta use rake -D or something...

Comment: I think It should be some where in the repo i liked in comments you as the .idea files are generated when the project is open with IDE also the repo as .idea folder which i think is a reference copy that may be copied on project start.

Comment: So if i open a rails project with Sublime/Gedit/Notepad then i wont have .idea folder at all ?

Answer (score 1):

A useful addition to a `~/.gitignore` for gitters:

```
# ignore JetBrains IDE stuff
.idea
.generators
```